# Read XML with Elements and csv's into 2D array using XDocument in C#/XNA

Tags: c#, xml, linq, multidimensional-array, linq-to-xml

I have an XML File with Elements that look like the following:

```
<level>
        <name>Name of Level 1</name>
        <number>1</number>
        <authorTime>8.55</authorTime>
        <scoringTime>20</scoringTime>
        <map width="19" height="15"><!--Level1-->
            <row>0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0</row>
            <row>2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,-1,-1,0,1,0,-1,2,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,2</row>
            <row>0,1,0,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,0,1,0,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,2,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,-1,3,2,-1,0,-1,2,-1,0,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,2,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,2,-1,2</row>
            <row>0,1,0,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,2,-1,-1,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,1,1,0,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,2,-1,2,-1,0,-1,-1,2,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,2,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,-1,0,0,-1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,1,0,-1,2</row>
            <row>2,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2</row>
            <row>0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0</row>
        </map>
    </level>
```

And I want to use an XDocument (in C#/XNA) to read the "map" into a 2D rectangular array (y,x) - so in this example case it would be int[15,19].

All I can think of is creating a jagged array and converting to a rectangular one later - something like

```
int[][] test = ((from level in xDoc.Descendants("level")
                select (from map in level.Element("map")
                            select (from row in map.Elements("row")
                                    select (int.Parse(row.Value))).ToArray()).ToArray()));
```

But I know I need a string split on commas in here somewhere; and anyway I get a "select not found" error on level.Element("map").

My finished array should look like {{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2},...

Can anyone help?

--EDIT--

I now have:

```
    var test = (from level in xDoc.Descendants("level")
                    select (from row in level.Elements("map").Elements("row")
                        select (from col in row.Value.Split(',')
                            select (int.Parse(col))).ToArray()).ToArray());
```

which is giving me the data I want, but the "test" output is showing up in the debug as being of type: `{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement,int[][]>}`

Getting closer, but still not quite right!

Comment: Tou have to shuffle your `)` around. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it

```
select (from row in map.Elements("row").Value.Split(',')
        select (int.Parse(row) ...
```

And then it might just make sense to call it `col` instead of `row`.

> All I can think of is creating a jagged array and converting to a rectangular one later

Why convert?  A jagged array seems fine.

---

**Edit**

I gave it a test :

```
        var test =
            from level in doc.Descendants("level")
            select (from map in level.Elements("map")
                select (from row in map.Elements("row")
                        select (from col in row.Value.Split(',') 
                          select int.Parse(col)).ToArray()).ToArray() );
```

Which gives you an `IEnumerabl<IEnumerable<int[][]>>` (level and map lists).

So `test.First().First()` is your first array.

Comment: Other code uses the data I will be reading as a rectangular array - but that's the easy bit :)